# How to define a Weil divisor from a Cartier divisor on a variety?

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, definition, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible variety. Here are the definitions I'm working with (from Shafarevich).

A *Weil divisor* on $X$ is a formal finite sum of irreducible closed codimension 1 subvarieties of $X$. A *Cartier divisor* is "a system of rational functions $\{f_i\}$ corresponding to the open sets $U_i$ of a cover $X=\cup U_i$ satisfying both conditions: (1) the $f_i$ are not identically 0; (2) $f_i/f_j$ and $f_j/f_i$ are both regular on $U_i\cap U_j$."

I don't understand Shafarevich's description of how to define a Weil divisor from a Cartier divisor. He says that "any compatible system of functions defines a [Weil] divisor on $X$. Indeed, for a prime divisor $C$, we set $k_C=v_C(f_i)$ if $U_i\cap C\neq \emptyset $". He mentions that $k_C$ is independent of the choice of $i$ by compatibility, and thus we end up with a divisor $D=\sum k_C C$.

> Does this mean that, given a Cartier divisor $(U_i, f_i)$, to define the Weil divisor we need only fix some $f=f_i$ and compute $v_C(f)$ for that $f$ only?

I was trying to do what I thought might be an easy example, but I'm having trouble with the computations. Can someone help or critique where I'm going wrong? Let $H\subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$ be a hyperplane defined by $F(X,Y,Z)=aX+bY+cZ=0$. Then $H$ is an irreducible codimension 1 subvariety and therefore $H$ is a Weil divisor. If $U_i=\mathbb A _i^2$ is the standard affine cover of $\mathbb P^2$ then we also have Cartier divisor $(U_i, f_i)$, where $f_0=F/X, f_1=F/Y, f_2=F/Z$. It would make a lot of sense that the Weil divisor determined by $(U_i, f_i)$ be equal to $H$, but it doesn't seem to be... By definition, it suffices to compute $k_C=v_C(f_0)$ for every prime divisor $C$. (What is the best way to do this?) I think the only prime divisors $C$ where $v_C(f_0)$ is nonzero are $C=H$ and $C=(X=0)$, where I've found $v_H(f_0)=1$ and $v_{(X=0)}(f_0)=-1$. Thus it seems like the Weil divisor determined by $(U_i, f_i)$ is $H-H_0$ (not $H$!), where $H_0=(X=0)$. This seems wrong to me... Can someone help?

Comment: To my taste, the definition in Shafarevich is a bit awkward because at this point he's missing the machinery of sheaves. Intuitively, I think of the functions $f_i$ as local equations of a divisor in the neighbourhood $U_i$. Because the language of "local equations" is missing (I believe), he defines $f_i$ as global rational functions, but then to capture the local nature he adds the requirement that $C \cap U_i \neq \emptyset$. In your example, this is the issue --- $X = 0$ is disjoint from $U_0$. The "local function" obtained by restricting $f_0$ to $U_0$ doesnt "see" $\{X=0\}$.

Comment: Let $X=P^1(\Bbb{C})$ the Riemann sphere and $M=\Bbb{C}(z)$ its field of meromorphic functions and $O_X(U)$ the subring of those having no poles on $U\subset X$. Then $X$ is covered by two open sets $U_1=\Bbb{C}, U_2=1/\Bbb{C}$. Let $ P=0\in X$, there is no meromorphic function $f\in M$ whose divisor is $Div(f)=P$, to represent $P$ as a Cartier divisor, let $f_1(z)=z,f_2(z)=1$, for any (simply connected or affine) open set V, if $V\subset U_j$ send $V\to f_jO_X(V)^\times$. On $U_1\cap U_2$, $f_1/f_2$ has no poles/zeros so this is well-defined. Cartier divisors are naturally a group.

Comment: @reuns I think in the definition of Shafarevich, we can take the same two meromorphic functions, namely $f_1(z)=z$ (corresponding to $U_1$) and $f_2(z)=1$ (corresponding to $U_2$), both considered as meromorphic functions on $X$. Though $\operatorname{Div}(f_1) = P - \infty$ and $\operatorname{Div}(f_2) = 0$, since $\infty \notin U_1$, the corresponding Weil divisor (Shafarevich-I-Style) is $P$. But I strongly prefer the sheafy way as well.

Comment: @reuns it is true that no meromorphic function defines a divisor equal to a single point. That shows it is not a principal Weil divisor. But as Jane Doe shows, it can be represented as a Cartier Divisor. Furthermore, Well and Cartier divisors agree on $S^2$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide an answer to this question, let me expand Jane Doé's comment.

Fitst, let me clarify two things:

i) There are many members within this Community who know much more than me about these topics, and it should be they who provided a full answer.

ii) In order to give some intuition behind Shafarevich's reasoning, I will talk about the *zeros* of functions, instead of valuation rings. This means I am refuising to use schemes as much as possible. Both picturesd are quivalent, though, and one can say

- $v_Y(f) = k$ if $f$ vanishes along $Y$ (or rather, along $Y\cap U_i$) up to order $k$
- $v_Y(f)=-k$ if $1/f$ vanishes along $Y$ up to order $k$
- $v_Y(f)=0$ otherwise.

(I have just discoeverd that The Stacks Project give concrete recipes to compute the valuations $v_Y$ when they talk about Divisors [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02AQ). If you came up with an explicit proof of such equivalence, please let me know.)

In full generality, Carier divisors are global sections of the quotient sheaf $\mathscr K^*/\mathscr O^*_X$, where $\mathscr O_X$ is the structure sheaf of the variety and $\mathscr K$ is that of meromorphic functions (I do not know if that was the sheafy approach some users were looking forward to, for me there is no much difference).
Because I am not familiar with GAGA equivalence, I think of $\mathscr K$ as the sheaf of rings associated to the presheaf

$$
U\longmapsto S(U)^{-1}(U)\Gamma(U,\mathscr O_X),
$$

where $S(U)$ denotes the local sections $s$ over $U$ such that $s_x \in\mathscr O_{X,x}$ are not zero divisors, $x\in U$.
This is actually the general definition of $\mathscr K$, which I guess turns out to be equivalent to the sheaf of meromorphic functions for well-behaved schemes.

Because of the definition of the quotient sheaf, a global section of $\mathscr K^*/\mathscr O_X^*$ is equivalent to giving elements $f_i\in \Gamma(U_i,\mathscr K)$ such that $f_if_j^{-1}$ are in the subgroup $\Gamma(U_i\cap U_j,\mathscr O_X^*$ whenever $U_i\cap U_j$ are non-empty.

Now, $v_Y(D)$ is all about the local nature of $D$ around the generic point $\eta$ of $Y$, which is encode in the local piece $f_i$.
If $U_i$ does not contain $\eta$, then tehere is nothing to say and $v_Y(D)=0$.
Assume then that $\eta\in U_i$, and, moreover, that $\eta \in U_j$, for some $j\neq i$.
Then $f_i=rf_j$ for some invertible element $r\in\Gamma(U_i\cap U_j,\mathscr O_X^*)$, so that $f_i$ and $f_j$ ''have the same zeros and poles'' and thus $v_Y(D)=v_Y(f_i)=v_Y(f_j)$.

**Remark.** In full generality, once needs to be carefull when talking about zeros and poles of sections of $\mathscr K$.

This is easily seen for curves because Weil divisors are formal sum of points.
Suppose furthermore that our curve is quasi-projective (I do not know if that is completely necessary), so that we can expand functions using Laurent series.
For a point $x$ in the domain of the $i$-th piece $f_i$ defining a Cartier divisor $D$, set $v_x(D)$ to be the unique integer $k$ such that $a_k$ is the first non-trivial term in the Laurent expansion of $f_i$ around $x$ (once more, this should be equivalent to any previous definition given so far).
If $x$ is also in the domian of another piece $f_j$, then $f_i$ and $f_j$ are related by a nowhere-vanishing function $r$, meaning that the integer $k$, as just defined, remains unchanged.
Of course if $x$ is not in the definition of $f_j$, $v_x(D)$ cannot be computed using $f_j$.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610507/correspondence-between-cartier-divisor-and-weil-divisor-hartshorne-proposition) is also about the morphism $CaCl(X) \to Cl(X)$, but as treated in Hartshorne.
To be honest, I cannot see there is much difference between one another, and in my opinion both resemble Grothendieck's approach.