# Group of Divisor classes compared to Weil and Cartier Divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hi this article http://www.ams.org/notices/200302/what-is.pdf mentioned "$p − q$ in the group of divisor classes $H^{1}(M, O^{∗})$, where $M$ is the elliptic curve and $O^{∗}$ is the sheaf of nonzero holomorphic functions on it."

In the last three years of practicing math I have just been learning divisors are formal sums of the order of a function along a cover or the 1-codimensional subvarieties. I don't know how to write the subvariety or cover in the product of the order yet but I don't see how the zero $p$ and pole $q$ are expected to fit in there.

May I have a brief explanation of the difference between the Weil and Cartier divisor and the divisor class mentioned in the article?

Comment: Plenty of textbooks deal with this in depth, and it would be a good idea to start with one of those if you're serious about the subject (if you're more interested in just decoding this article, that might be another matter). Vakil's [Foundations of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) touches on them in chapter 14, while Hartshorne deals with them in chapter II section 6.

Comment: There are some other good questions on this site about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610507/correspondence-between-cartier-divisor-and-weil-divisor-hartshorne-proposition